# authenicate OpenSUSE 10.2 client to CentOS 6.6 LDAP server

Tags: centos, opensuse, authentication, ldap

In our company, we have a network where I installed a working LDAP server for our CentOS 6 servers (FTP/WEB/Pydio/VOD/etc servers) about 25 of them. All working perfectly with LDAP authentication.

Next to that we have about 120 slightly outdated (cannot update them) OpenSuse 10.2 servers. Those have an installer given to us by the supplier of that 'special' machines and we cannot go to a newer distribution. I would like these 120 nodes to authenticate on the CentOS LDAP server as well, but with those I run into issues.

I used `yast` to setup the ldap_client configuration, but when I try to login I got the message:

```
Failed publickey for user... of IP 10.11.12.13 port 30891
```

After typing the password I got a second message:

```
Failed password for user... of IP 10.11.12.13 port 30891
```

Each time a different port. Also tried several users all result in the same messages.

So I tried to google what could go wrong, but there isn't anyone that matches these 2 distro's and posted some details how to.

On CentOS I could (and did) use the authconfig tool and without any issues all working.
I guess for these OpenSuSE systems I have to alter some things manually.

Last thing I found but not sure of is that OpenSuSE still uses SHA512 hashing and CentOS6.x uses SHA1024 Hashing, but I also found some contradictions on that as well.

Edit: output of /etc/ldap.conf

```
#Stripped all comments only actual values to reduce size. 
host 172.23.3.1 
base dc=nmc 
bind_policy soft 
pam_password exop 
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers root,ldap 
nss_schema rfc2307bis 
nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member 
ssl no ldap_version 3 
pam_filter objectclass=posixAccount 
nss_base_passwd dc=nmc 
nss_base_shadow dc=nmc 
nss_base_group dc=nmc 
tls_checkpeer no
```

Comment: My goodness is that old (not to mention a huge security risk). Can you post the output of `/etc/ldap.conf` for the SuSE Box? I'm going to take a guess that something isn't right in `pam_password`.

Comment: here it is:`DHCP-IP16:/publitronic/objects/code # cat /etc/ldap.conf 

    #Stripped all comments only actual values to reduce size.
    host 172.23.3.1
    
    base dc=nmc
    
    bind_policy soft
    
    pam_password exop
    
    nss_initgroups_ignoreusers root,ldap
    
    nss_schema rfc2307bis
    
    nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member
    
    ssl no
    ldap_version 3
    pam_filter objectclass=posixAccount
    nss_base_passwd dc=nmc
    nss_base_shadow dc=nmc
    nss_base_group dc=nmc
    tls_checkpeer no`

Comment: Looks hiddious..... :(

Comment: I've edited your original question to reflect this output.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the current setting on the OpenSUSE boxes are set to exop. Where can I find in the centos 6 LDAP server config what to use? Or is it trial and error for this...

Comment: What I did so far: I deleted all lines in the /etc/ldap.conf and only left the lines: 

    base dc=nmc
    uri ldap://172.23.3.1/
    pam_password exop

Now I'm able to use the LDAP user logins on the machine it self, but I still can't use it when loggin in via an SSH terminal to that Machine. That is quite essencial. Any suggestions anyone...?

Comment: You need to edit `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/common-account`

Comment: both contain the lines auth or account with sufficient pam_inix2.so and pam.ldap.so and on the pam_ldap.so the option use_first_pass is added.

Comment: Yesterday I got it to work on the local terminal as mentioned before, but via putty or ssh not yet. But I found the issue on that as well :)

The ssh deamon wasn't setup to use PAM, so changed #UsePAM yes to UsePAM yes

:) Thanks you all for the suggestions it did point me in the correct directions, just had to fine tune it :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I might clean this up and write it as an actual answer and leave a space for you to add in `sshd_config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it seems that the problem isn't with the LDAP server as other servers and machines were able to authenticate without problem.

My thoughts were to look at `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/common-account` to have OpenSuSE read from those files for authentication.

Comment: Not required anymore, but this was indeed the trick. Thanks.